# How can I move a JFrame to specific Location more smoothly than "teleporting" it with setLocation()?

Tags: java, swing, loops, jframe, location

Im trying to build a methode "move()" with which I can animate the way from the start to the end location when moving a JFrame with the frame.setLocation(int x, int y) method. I tried the following and it put the frame in the right spot but the problem is that the animation goes down on the x-axis first and only afterward goes down the y-axis but my goal was to make it seem like a diagonal movement to the destination point. I know its because of the first forLoops because they are not having the right conditions for breaking the process of the setLocation methods into single parts but I have absolutely no clue how to solve this problem.

```
public int currentX() {
    return (int) frame.getLocation().getX();
}

public int currentY() {
    return (int) frame.getLocation().getY();
}

public void move(int x, int y) {
    for (int newX = currentX(); newX < x; newX++) {
        frame.setLocation(currentX() + 1, currentY());
        for(int newY = currentY(); newY < y; newY++) {
            frame.setLocation(currentX(), currentY() + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Swing is single thread, you will need to move the `for-loop` off the main thread.  Swing is also not thread safe, so any modifications to the state of the UI should be done within the context of the main (Event Dispatching) thread - catch 22 - the simplest solution is to use a Swing `Timer`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to animate an entire Jframe in Java so that it moves?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950694/is-there-a-way-to-animate-an-entire-jframe-in-java-so-that-it-moves)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swing is single thread, you will need to move the `for-loop` off the main thread.  Swing is also not thread safe, so any modifications to the state of the UI should be done within the context of the main (Event Dispatching) thread - catch 22 - the simplest solution is to use a Swing `Timer`

See [How to use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new JLabel("Hello"));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        move(frame, 100, 100);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    public static void move(JFrame frame, int deltaX, int deltaY) {
        int xMoveBy = deltaX > 0 ? 4 : -4;
        int yMoveBy = deltaY > 0 ? 4 : -4;

        int targetX = frame.getX() + deltaX;
        int targetY = frame.getY() + deltaY;

        Timer timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int frameX = frame.getX();
                int frameY = frame.getY();
                if (deltaX > 0) {
                    frameX = Math.min(targetX, frameX + xMoveBy);
                } else {
                    frameX = Math.max(targetX, frameX - xMoveBy);
                }
                if (deltaY > 0) {
                    frameY = Math.min(targetY, frameY + yMoveBy);
                } else {
                    frameY = Math.max(targetY, frameY - yMoveBy);
                }

                frame.setLocation(frameX, frameY);
                if (frameX == targetX && frameY == targetY) {
                    ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
                }
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast solution. I tried out your code and it worked perfectly. Now I really have to read a lot about the thing you used since I dont understand much of it and thought it would be much easier to realize my idea.

Comment: @NarcatasCor Animation in Swing is not difficult per say, but it requires a different approach and mindset

Answer (score -1):

Your second loop runs until completed, you need to move the frame simultaneously and only increment `X` or `Y` when needed!

```
public int currentX() {
    return (int) frame.getLocation().getX();
}

public int currentY() {
    return (int) frame.getLocation().getY();
}

public void move(int x, int y) {
    for (int newX = currentX(), newY = currentY(); newX < x || newY < y;     ) {
        frame.setLocation(newX, newY);
        if (newX < x) newX++;
        if (newY < y) newY++;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I've tried too and while its true that the animation in this case will be move the window in a diagnonal way, the end location will be wrong.

Comment: This will still block the Event Dispatching Thread resulting no change in the results the OP is experiencing

Comment: @MadProgrammer But he clearly said "the animation goes down on the x-axis first and only afterward goes down the y-axis" This means he noticed the animation, so I guess he didn't launch it from the main thread and that wasn't his actual problem to begin with! Why would I fix something that wasn't broken!